# WINUI 3 apply font to all controls

Tags: xaml, fonts, winui-3

I want to change font in my WinUI 3 application. Just everywhere. I found a few answers here on SO, but they all seem to apply font to target like `TextBlock`, `Button` etc. The app I'm about to style has many different controls.

In CSS I'd simply do something like

```
* {
  font-family: Verdana;
}
```

Is there a way to achieve something like that in WinUI 3? Specify the default font name on one place, without naming all possible controls used in the app?

---

Edit: after trying the @Andrew KeepCoding approach, it works but not for all controls:

[image: screenshot of the app with some controls not styled]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding the `ContentControlThemeFontFamily` should work, though, there are cases, like `TextBlock`, that you need to set the `FontFamily` explicitly.

```xml
<Application
    x:Class="App16.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App16">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
                <!-- Other merged dictionaries here -->
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- Other app resources here -->
            <FontFamily x:Key="ContentControlThemeFontFamily">Courier New</FontFamily>
            <Style
                x:Key="TitleTextBlockStyle"
                BasedOn="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"
                TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Regarding to the custom font you mentioned in the comments, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76908883/installing-custom-fonts-in-a-c-winui-3-application/76909949#76909949) might help.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! It seems to work, not for all controls, weirdly enough not for TextBlocks. I'll attach a screenshot.

Comment: I added screenshot. No styles are defined on page level or control level. Also, the approach also does NOT work for me (at all) with fonts from Asserss/Fonts/Jost folder (custom ttf font, build action is set to Content).

Comment: As @Katana suggests, there are controls that you need to set the `FontFamily` explicitly. Check my updated answer.

Comment: I'm still having troubles with the heading ("Project" on the screenshot, the yellow highlighted area). It seems to be using TitleTextBlockStyle from generic.xaml. Any chance to override that one? Suggested solutions do not seem to have any effect on those.

Comment: You can also override `Style`s. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

WinUI 3 uses the following FontFamily, so you must Overwrite the following fonts. You have overwritten the `ContentControlThemeFontFamily`, so try the other ones

```
 <FontFamily x:Key="ContentControlThemeFontFamily">XamlAutoFontFamily</FontFamily>
            <FontFamily x:Key="MTCMediaFontFamily">XamlAutoFontFamily</FontFamily>
            <FontFamily x:Key="PhoneFontFamilyNormal">Segoe WP</FontFamily>
            <FontFamily x:Key="PhoneFontFamilySemiLight">Segoe WP SemiLight</FontFamily>
            <FontFamily x:Key="PivotHeaderItemFontFamily">XamlAutoFontFamily</FontFamily>
            <FontFamily x:Key="PivotTitleFontFamily">XamlAutoFontFamily</FontFamily>
            <FontFamily x:Key="SymbolThemeFontFamily">Segoe Fluent Icons,Segoe MDL2 Assets</FontFamily>
            <FontFamily x:Key="KeyTipFontFamily">XamlAutoFontFamily</FontFamily>
```

also you can overwrite specific control like this, so you dont need to overwrite above fonts:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
  <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource myFont}"/>
</Style>
```